# How can I get Express.js to 404 only on missing routes?

Tags: node.js, express

At the moment I have the following which sits below all my other routes:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
  console.log('404ing');
  res.render('404');
});
```

And according to the logs, it is being fired even when the route is being matched above.  How can I get it to only fire when nothing is matched?

Comment: to support @Charles' answer, I just wanted to tell that the URL to the Express documentation page has moved to the FAQ [http://expressjs.com/starter/faq.html#how-do-you-handle-404s](http://expressjs.com/starter/faq.html#how-do-you-handle-404s)

Comment: See http://expressjs.com/en/starter/faq.html#how-do-i-handle-404-responses

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You just need to put it at the end of all route.

Take a look at the second example of [Passing Route Control](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#passing-route%20control):

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express.createServer();

var users = [{ name: 'tj' }];

app.all('/user/:id/:op?', function(req, res, next){
  req.user = users[req.params.id];
  if (req.user) {
    next();
  } else {
    next(new Error('cannot find user ' + req.params.id));
  }
});

app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res){
  res.send('viewing ' + req.user.name);
});

app.get('/user/:id/edit', function(req, res){
  res.send('editing ' + req.user.name);
});

app.put('/user/:id', function(req, res){
  res.send('updating ' + req.user.name);
});

app.get('*', function(req, res){
  res.status(404).send('what???');
});
```

Blockquote

```
app.listen(3000);
```

Alternatively you can do nothing because all route which does not match will produce a 404. Then you can use this code to display the right template:

```
app.error(function(err, req, res, next){
    if (err instanceof NotFound) {
        res.render('404.jade');
    } else {
        next(err);
    }
});
```

It's documented in [Error Handling](http://expressjs.com/guide/error-handling.html).

Comment: Note that `res.send('what???', 404);` is deprecated , use `res.status(404).send('what???');` instead.

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: Note that `app.error()` was removed in 3.x. Use `app.use()` instead passing in the same middleware above. 

https://github.com/expressjs/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x

Answer (score 14):

I bet your browser is following up with a request for the favicon.  That is why you are seeing the 404 in your logs after the 200 success for the requested page.

Setup a favicon route.

Comment: So, basically: `app.get('*.ico', function(){})`. I never serve `.ico` files from my node server, so I didn't need to be any more restrictive than that.

You can confirm that this is the issue by going to a defined route in your browser versus going to that same route using ajax, or curl or something like that.

Comment: Holy cow. I was able to confirm that that was my problem by just dropping `console.log("/* =>", req.originalUrl);` in the fallback route. I can't believe that was it. Thanks!

Comment: In my case it was a missing file but my error reporting didn't show the URL. It does now...

Answer (score 8):

You can this at the end of all routes,

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8080;

// All your routes and middleware here.....

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.status(404).json({
        message: 'Ohh you are lost, read the API documentation to find your way back home :)'
    })
})

// Init the server here,
app.listen( port, () => {
    console.log('Sever is up')
})
```

Answer (score 6):

Hope it helpful, I used this code in bottom of routes

```
router.use((req, res, next) => {
    next({
        status: 404,
        message: 'Not Found',
    });
});

router.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (err.status === 404) {
        return res.status(400).render('404');
    }

    if (err.status === 500) {
        return res.status(500).render('500');
    }

   next();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
const express = require('express');
const app=express();
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.get('/', (req,res,next)=>{
    res.render('home');
});
app.use( (req,res,next)=>{
    res.render('404');
})
app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted a catch all that would render my 404 page only on missing routes and found it here in the error handling docs https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack)
  res.status(404).render('404.ejs')
})
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple you can add this middleware.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
//Capture All 404 errors
  res.status(404).render("404.ejs")
})
```

404 error in a service is typically used to denote that the requested resource is not available. In this article we will see how to handle 404 error in express.

Answer (score 0):

**We need to handle the Error and Not-Found collectively as**

Write two separate middleware for each,

```
// Import necessary modules
const express = require('express');

// Create a new Express app
const app = express();

// Define routes and middleware functions
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

// Catch 404 Not Found errors and forward to error handler
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const error = new Error('Not Found');
    error.status = 404;
    next(error);
});

// Error handler middleware function
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    // Set status code and error message based on error object
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.send({
        error: {
            message: err.message
        }
    });
});

// Start the server
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});
```