# Express Routing - Root Page and 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on a Node app that uses Express. In this app, I have the following:

```
app.use('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', {});            
});
```

This route works fine for the positive case. However, it fails for the negative case. For example, If I visit "http://www.example.com/404", I still see the index page. In reality, I want it to fall through so that the Express Error handler tackles the error.

How do I change my route so that when a person visits the root of my app, they see the home page. yet, if they enter anything else, they'll see the 404 page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get Express.js to 404 only on missing routes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500204/how-can-i-get-express-js-to-404-only-on-missing-routes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `app.get()` (or *possibly* [`app.all()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.all)), not `app.use()`:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', {});
});
```

The reason why `app.use('/', ...)` matches `/404` is explained [here](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use):

> A route will match any path that follows its path immediately with a “/”. For example: `app.use('/apple', ...)` will match “/apple”, “/apple/images”, “/apple/images/news”, and so on.

Comment: Interesting. I had not idea. Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

You can define middleware to specifically handle errors.

Express error-handling middleware takes four arguments and should be defined after all your other routes:

```
app.use('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', {});            
}); 

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
});
```