# Authenticating the request header with Express

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, aop, access-token

I want to verify that all our get requests have a specific token in their authentication header.

I can add this to our get endpoints:

```
app.get('/events/country', function(req, res) {
    if (!req.headers.authorization) {
    return res.json({ error: 'No credentials sent!' });
    }
```

Is there any better way to handle this in NodeJS/Express without changing every endpoint? something like a before-filter/AOP approach?

Comment: You can write a simple express middleware which checks the authorization header for every HTTP request received. Make sure to app.use() the middleware before you handle any routes

Answer (score 99, accepted):

That's what [middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) is for:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.headers.authorization) {
    return res.status(403).json({ error: 'No credentials sent!' });
  }
  next();
});

...all your protected routes...
```

Make sure that the middleware is declared *before* the routes to which the middleware should apply.

Comment: to get the request header, recommended way is `req.get('authorization')`

Comment: @BoLu recommended by whom?

Comment: it is in the [Express official doc](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.get)

Comment: @BoLu but it doesn't say anywhere that using `req.get` is recommended. The same documentation also states that _"The req object is an enhanced version of Node’s own request object and supports all built-in fields and methods"_, so I don't see a reason why someone shouldn't be using `req.headers`.

Comment: True, you can use `req.headers`. But here we're talking about Express and `req.get` just appears at the top level of its document, so it should be the idiomatic way to get request headers when using Express.

Comment: I want to use this but it messes up the catch-all 404 I have at the bottom of my script https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500204/how-can-i-get-express-js-to-404-only-on-missing-routes

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride in that case, add the proposed middleware separately to each route that needs to be protected (`app.use('/protected', auth_middleware, handler)`). Alternatively, you can prefix the routes that need to be protected and use a separate `express.Router` (`app.use('/protected', auth_middleware, router)`) ([example here](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/d4095a127671ee2da65c046208bed8ad)).

Comment: @robertklep thanks, writing a middleware function was easier than I expected!

Comment: For those using typescript, please don't use the `req.get(item: string)` suggestion for anything.  It can not be inspected, it won't return proper types, and -- in general -- using string ids offer zero feedback when debugging.

Comment: A year later, I'm at this problem again from a different side.  `req.get()` is case insensitive, and that can sometimes save you from confusing errors.

Answer (score 3):

```
const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
if(!token) return res.send("No credentials");
// next(); // Let the user proceed
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with a more modular approach to chain validations, creating a middleware with a validator library specifically designed for express: [express-validator](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/).

Example of expected header `Authorization: Bearer c8f27fee2a579fa4c3fa580`

1. Install `express-validator` package:

   `npm install --save express-validator` OR `yarn add express-validator`

---

2. Create a middleware (e.g. in path `src/middlewares/validators.js`)

```js
import { header, validationResult } from "express-validator";

export const myRequestHeaders = [
  header('authorization')
    .exists({ checkFalsy: true })
    .withMessage("Missing Authorization Header") // you can specify the message to show if a validation has failed
    .bail() // not necessary, but it stops execution if previous validation failed
    //you can chain different validation rules 
    .contains("Bearer")
    .withMessage("Authorization Token is not Bearer")
];

export function validateRequest(req, res, next) {
  const validationErrors = validationResult(req);
  const errorMessages = [];

  for (const e of validationErrors.array()) {
    errorMessages.push(e.msg);
  }

  if (!validationErrors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(403).json({ "errors": errorMessages });
  }
  next();
}
```

---

3. use validator middlewares in your endpoint.

   **IMPORTANT**: you need use the middlewares before your actual route function. Also, you need to chain the middleware such that the `validateRequest` function (which actually verifies the validity of your request) comes after the expected header validator, in this case `myRequestHeader`. See below:

```js
app.use('/api/v1/your-endpoint', myRequestHeaders, validateRequest, async (req, res) => {
  // the validator middleware will have already thrown a 403 if the header was missing,
  // so you can be 100% sure that the header is present with validations your created.
  console.log("req.headers.authorization", req.headers.authorization);
  
  // do whatever you want
  const actualToken = getBearerTokenFromHeader(req.headers.authorization); // c8f27fee2a579fa4c3fa580

  res.sendStatus(200);
})

// helper function to get token value
const getBearerTokenFromHeader = (authToken) => {
  return authToken.split(" ")[1]
}
```

With this library you can check the presence and quality of headers, parameters, body data and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can get from request header  **req.header**

```
const verifyTokenMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  const { token } = req.headers;
  if (!token) {
  return res.status(401).json({ msg: "No token present"});
  }
 try {
 // decoded token here and more
 } catch (err) { 
 }
  next()
 };
```