# Express - How to redirect to 404 page and send 404 status

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, frontend

After a long research and trial & error, couldnt get things to work so i'll try to ask here.

i have a website and if i go to http://my-domain.com/non-exist-page than i'v got redirect to 404 page with status of 302.
so far so good.

but i want to display my 404 page with the status 404, somethings like
you can see if you go to http://google.com/sdfsw for example.
[image]

did someone got this thing to work?
thanx in advanced

Comment: Well, the Google example isn't actually redirecting to a different URL. It just shows the 404 page with a 404 status. Why don't you just show the 404 page instead of redirecting to a specific 404 url?

Answer (score 4):

you have to add default app.get for handle this 404 errors.

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/page404.html'));
});
```

**Note :** you have to place this line of code after all your route.

Answer (score 1):

Use error handling and render or route to a view of your own design.

http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

You can also find some great tips in this thread: 
[How can I get Express.js to 404 only on missing routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500204/how-can-i-get-express-js-to-404-only-on-missing-routes)

Comment: yes. i accept this solution or you have to use sendfile file command in http.get("*")