# Nodejs - if path /api - serve api, if not - serve static files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My issue seems complicated for me but I guess its simple for experienced nodejs developers. All I want is that my api responds to api calls only if the url is `/api/~`, but if any other - `/` or `/somethingElse` or anything - serve static files.

My code:

```
var app = express();

app.get("/api/users", function (req, res) {
    getUsers(function (err, users) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send('Error');
        }

        return res.json(users);
    });
});

app.get("/api/user/:_id", function (req, res) {
    getUserById(req.params._id, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send('Error');
        }

        return res.json(user);
    });
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, you're looking for `express.static`

### Setting Directory To Serve Static Files

Assume you have a 'public' directory that contains static assets.

public

- img

  - img1.png
  - img2.png
- css

  - style.css

Here's how to make them all accessible:

```
const path = require('path')

express.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

**Note:** Your path to the public directory might be in a different location, just add the relevant path arguments to `path.join()`.

Now the following will be accessible:

- /img/img1.png
- /img/img2.png
- /css/style.css

[See Express dos for static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

### Express Router

Now, because that you're looking to use various routes starting with `/api`, you might find it useful to use `express.Router`. Create an `express.Router()` for each base path. For example, create one called `apiRouter` for routes starting with '/api'. Once the router is defined, just call `app.use()` with the base path and the `apiRouter`:

```
let apiRouter = express.Router()

// GET /api/users
apiRouter.get('/users', (res, res, next) => {})

// GET /api/users/:id
apiRouter.get('/users/:id', (req, res, next) => {})

// prefix apiRouter with '/api'
app.use('/api', apiRouter)
```

Comment: Thanks, but now it doesnt work if I e.g. paste link `example.com/user:1` into browser, I get `Cannot GET /user/1`

Comment: Okey, adding another middleware - `app.use('/*'. 'public')` did the job. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

After all your api routes you need to define a / route that serves static files

In your case:

```
app.get("/api/users", function (req, res) {
   ...
});

app.get("/api/user/:_id", function (req, res) {
    ...
});


app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, './'))); // or whatever path you need
```

Read more in the [official docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

Comment: path = require('path') is needed, note this

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your word 100%..
I guess your word.

I think that you connect static files when not api url page.
If this correct, you click this page. [How can I get Express.js to 404 only on missing routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500204/how-can-i-get-express-js-to-404-only-on-missing-routes)