# welcome page with '/' and page not found for rest

Tags: node.js, express

I have just started working on Nodejs express routers

```
app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "views", "welcome.html"));
});
```

this will route me to http://localho.st:3000**/**  to welcome page

***I want to redirect the rest of the non-available pages to page not found***, I tried following, I know above and below code is same based on first come first served basis it will execute.

**but I want to know how else I can handle this(to route all other pages other than '/' to 404)?**

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.send('<h1>Page Not Found ! </h1>');
});
```

I also tried-- with ref: to comment #1

```
app.use('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "views", "welcome.html"));
});

app.get('*',(req, res) => {
    res.send('<h1>Page Not Found ! </h1>');
});
```

**Answer** . : `changed app.use('/',...) to app.get('/',...) worked for me`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get Express.js to 404 only on missing routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500204/how-can-i-get-express-js-to-404-only-on-missing-routes)

Comment: I tried to have two middleware with / and * with respect to the above link, it is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only one reason why you got some error it's because you're add your middleware: `Not found` in the above of your all route. That's why you got some error.

Make sure your code looks like this code below:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "views", "welcome.html"));
});

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.send("<h1>Page Not Found ! </h1>");
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log("Server is up");
});
```

> After that, in the same directory, you can create your `views` folder and put your `welcome.html` in there.

**For an example**, you can see at my codeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-elion-p1hcj

Comment: Thanks for your help, But when I try running https://p1hcj.sse.codesandbox.io/Bfsa . it still goes to HelloWorld instead of page Not found, for example when we try to give some random path "/wefrw", it must go to page not found, but it says  "hello world "

Comment: It's because we're using method use to render our page, we can change it to method `get`. I've been change my code above and it's working fine. You can try it. I hope it can help you.