# Middleware priorities in node.js

Tags: node.js

Hey i want to run `main_page` file when i enter `/` router `main_page` is simply welcome page in which Welcome written on it and if anyone else type a random address like `/dsadad` i want it to show `404 pug file` while again `404` is simply a pug file with `Page not found` written in it but only main_page is running on home route and on random route as well but i want to show 404 error when someone enter random address

```
const express = require('express');
const app=express();
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use('/', (req,res,next)=>{
    res.render('home');
});
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.render('404');
})
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: order matters, simply move it below

Comment: @LawrenceCherone still same problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get Express.js to 404 only on missing routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500204/how-can-i-get-express-js-to-404-only-on-missing-routes)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i figured it out i changed app.use to app.get and it worked thanks btw

Answer (score 0):

I changed app.use to app.get and it worked for me

```
const express = require('express');
const app=express();
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.get('/', (req,res,next)=>{
    res.render('home');
});
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.render('404');
})
app.listen(3000);
```